# How can i set title in FF 61 using webext API

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I used several methods:

```
browser.browserAction.setTitle();
browser.tabs.update();
```

but none of them works.
Only document.title works.

Comment: What's wrong with using document.title?

Comment: What about using `window.eval('document.title="new title"')` in content script?